# Android; how can you invoke a SOAP web service without using ksoap?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I'm not asking to be spoon fed here, just need some pointers on where to direct my searching

I want to call a SOAP web service, possibly [this](http://webservices.gama-system.com/files/GetCurrentExchangeRatesXML.xml) one

I don't want to use KSoap, is there anyway I can do this using the apache libraries that are included with the Android SDK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consuming a SOAP webservice without ksoap2 in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706331/consuming-a-soap-webservice-without-ksoap2-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to call a SOAP web service, possibly this one

That does not look like a SOAP Web service. Try clicking that link in a browser, and you will see it is a plain XML document.

> is there anyway I can do this using the apache libraries that are included with the Android SDK?

Yes. For true SOAP, plan to spend a substantial amount of time writing your own SOAP layer atop HttpClient. However, for consuming a simple XML document like the one you link to above, it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think the XML is not WebService, it is simple XML... To call WebService with SOAP you can use kSOAP2 on Android platform, but I've created an another - proof-of-concept - SOAP client:
http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home