# Consuming a SOAP webservice without ksoap2 in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, soap, ksoap2

In my Android application, i'm using ksoap2 library for consuming a soap ( & .net) webservice. It works correctly but it's very slow (for parsing, controls, loops and Base64ToBinary processes). I want to parse it more fast. Is it possible to parse it without using ksoap2? Any ideas?
Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: How did you determine that it is slow? It certainly is not slow for me.

Comment: in this line -> androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
it's slow and using about 10 mb memory size. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean slow? It does a http request and then parses the response. You have to do this in an async task. Memory usage will depend on the response you get. Maybe you are requesting way too much. See the wiki on how to debug!

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem with KSoap2. Unfortunately, ksoap2 library is not working with my webservices. So at last, I have done with default http post.

I hope this will help for someone in future.

```
private String makeHttpRequest(){
        try{
            String request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                    +"<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                    + "<ns1:Connect>"
                    + "<ns1:lstr_Login>xxxxx</ns1:lstr_Login>"
                    +"</ns1:Connect>"
                    +"</SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                    +"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

            String soapAction = "http://tempuri.org/Connect"; //this would be your soapAction from wsdl

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request, HTTP.UTF_8);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(new URI("http://xxxxxxxx.com/Storefront.asmx"));

            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            int responseStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "HTTP Status code:"+responseStatusCode);
            if(responseStatusCode>=200 && responseStatusCode<300){
                //we got the success response from server. Now retrieve the value and go for usage.
                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                //use this responseStr to parse with pullparsers or any
                Log.d("Response", "Response:: "+ responseStr);
                return responseStr;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Write the proper catch blocks for exceptions
            Log.e("Response Exception" , e.getMessage()+"",e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How to send soap xml headers in httpPost?